# ReactNative - invariant violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeareview" was not found in the UI Manager

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo, safeareaview

I have created a react native package with expo-bare-workflow. I have also added the packages like,

```
npm install --save react-navigation
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
npm install --save react-navigation-stack

npm install --save @react-native-community/masked-view
npm install --save react-native-safe-area-view 
npm install --save react-native-safe-area-context

npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
npm install --save react-native-reanimated
```

Following is my App.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
  Button,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";

class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Please sign in',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Sign in!" onPress={this._signInAsync} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _signInAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc');
    this.props.navigation.navigate({
      routeName: 'Home',
      key: 'Home',
      params: { userInfo: 'lol' },
    });
  };
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome to the app!',
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // alert(JSON.stringify(this.props.navigation.state.params))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.props.navigation.state.params)}</Text>
        <Button title="Show me more of the app" onPress={this._showMoreApp} />
        <Button title="Actually, sign me out :)" onPress={this._signOutAsync} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _showMoreApp = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Other');
  };

  _signOutAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
  };
}

class OtherScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Lots of features here',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="I'm done, sign me out" onPress={this._signOutAsync} />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _signOutAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
  };
}

class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    if (userToken) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate({
        routeName: 'Home',
        key: 'Home',
        params: { userInfo: 'hello world' },
      });
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn');
    }
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  { Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen },
  { initialRouteKey: 'Home', initialRouteName: 'Home' }
);
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  },
),
);
```

But i am getting an error as shown in screenshot.

[image: Error Log]

Please suggest a solution.

Also, i want to know how to decide which packages will work with reactnative-cli, expo-managed-cli, expo bare-cli ?

Thanks.